# Android. getExternalStorageDirectory() depricated. Правильная работа с файловой системой?

Tags: android

Тестирую приложение на android 10.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` возвращает */storage/emulated/0*, но данная функция помечена как **deprecated**.

Из документации android:

> It's important that you use directory names provided by API constants
> like DIRECTORY_PICTURES. These directory names ensure that the files
> are treated properly by the system. If none of the pre-defined
> sub-directory names suit your files, you can instead pass null into
> getExternalFilesDir(). This returns the root app-specific directory
> within external storage.

Используя `getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()` получаю путь  */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files*.

Как я понял, писать пути напрямую очень плохая идея, т.к. на разных устройствах они разнятся. Но я не могу понять, есть ли аналог **deprecated** функции, который позволит получить путь к корню файловой системы **external storage**, т.е. */storage/emulated/0*.

Правка: Путь мне нужен для того, что бы создать папку в корне **external storage**, и в ней хранить файлы.

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Google отказывается от подобной работы с файлами. Начиная с API 29+ вы должны использовать один из следующих инструментов: [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=ru), [Media Store](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) и [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider).

Вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) можно почитать про эти изменения.

Что касается приложений, для которых нужен полный доступ к файловой системе - можно прочитать вот [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).

Comment: а как же тогда программы на подобии файловых менеджеров?

Comment: Там для таких штук есть решение. ЩА попробуй найти

Comment: Дополнил ответ .

Comment: Спасибо! Изучу подробнее документацию и думаю разобравшись сформирую подробный ответ. Т.к. найти именно эту статью я так и не смог, везде почти одни и те же ответы, на по разному сформулированные вопросы.